# Git: what is the difference between dev and refs/heads/dev?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-refspec

From recent work in devops, it seems as though there are "two ways" to check out a branch in git: using the plain branch name, e.g. `dev`, or using the branch name prefixed with `refs/heads/`, e.g. `refs/heads/dev`.

**What is the difference between the two?**

Certain HTTP POST content in the Bitbucket webhook to Jenkins gives the "`refs/head`" version of the branch. Other POST content gives the "basename" branch.
E.g. using (what I think is) Jenkins syntax to fetch POST content from a pull-request Bitbucket event, `$.pullRequest.fromRef.id` == `/refs/heads/dev`...
and `$.pullRequest.fromRef.displayId` == `dev`

In a cloned repository, checking out `refs/heads/dev` and `dev` resolves to the same SHAID, but their respective `stdout`s differ:

```
$ git checkout refs/heads/dev
Note: checking out 'refs/heads/dev'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at c320fd1... wip
```

```
$ git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
$ git log --oneline -n 1
c320fd1 wip
```

The `stdout` of the former looks the same as when you check out a SHAID.

Comment: Thats right. That's just how checkout works. Even if c320fd1 is dev, checkout c320fd1 is detached but checkout dev is not. They name the same commit but they are not synonymous. There's nothing more to know about that. It's just the rules of the game.

Comment: Similarly refs/heads/dev and dev. The latter means the former. `cat .git/refs/heads/dev` and see. Git looks for dev in refs/heads. But they are not synonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are resolved to revision id's early, according to [the rules in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem).

When the ref you give is resolved by (just) adding a `refs/heads/` prefix, Git's convenience machinery kicks in, `git checkout` will make `HEAD` be an alias for the branch tip, so all the convenience commands that rely on `HEAD` will be referring to and updating the branch tip ref.

So when you say `git checkout dev`, you're using Git's convenience machinery and it does the convenience thing for you, it wires `HEAD` to be a symbolic reference to `refs/heads/dev` and `git commit`'s `HEAD` update will be redirected to that branch tip.

But if you bypass the convenience logic by taking explicit steps yourself, that doesn't happen. That's really the sole difference. If you want, you can

```
git checkout refs/heads/dev 
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/dev
```

and now you've done Git's convenience processing yourself.